# Should I be at all concerned with seemingly arbitrary mass upvoting?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Every once in awhile, I'll see something like this:

[image: Upvote questions]

Now, none of the questions are bad *per se*, but some of them aren't great either. A couple had unformatted code, and after years of using the site, are questions that I just wouldn't expect to be upvoted. It looks like someone just rolled a die and upvoted an arbitrary series of questions.

Is this something I should be at all concerned about? Should I flag any of them? My main concern is that if someone's sock-puppeting, mass up voting posts around their own could take the attention off of their post.

Comment: What is "spotty mass up voting"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard That wasn't the best wording. I'll see if I can't fix the title. "Arbitrary" would have been a better word. I was using "spotty" to mean inconsistent.